# Pass a reference to setter

Tags: typescript

I have a private variable which I get/set using typescript getter/setter, for example:

```
private _x:number; 

set x(value:number){
   _x = value;
}

get x():number{
   return _x;
}
```

Is it possible to pass a reference to this setter so that I could use it later?
If I try to pass object.x, then it, of course get's the value of _x.

I know I could pass a string, "x", and then use it like obj["x"], but that would not be a good strongly-typed practice, plus, I would need to pass an object too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get a reference to the setter function from the property descriptor using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) on the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to your instance, then call it:

```
let setX:(x:number) => void = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(thing), "x").set.bind(thing);

setX(123);
```

But this is quite a lot of gymnastics. What I would do is just write a wrapping [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html):

```
let setX = (x:number):void => { thing.x = x };

setX(123);
```

This is simple and gives you inferred type safety. (For some reason the `{ }` is required for the compiler even though it emits the same JS either way.)

[Example in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Thing%20%7B%0A%09private%20_x%3Anumber%3B%0A%09public%20get%20x()%3Anumber%20%7B%20return%20this._x%3B%20%7D%0A%09public%20set%20x(n%3Anumber)%20%7B%20this._x%20%3D%20n%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20thing%20%3D%20new%20Thing()%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Option%201%3A%20Use%20property%20descriptor%0A%7B%20%0A%09let%20setX%3A(x%3Anumber)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(thing)%2C%20%22x%22).set.bind(thing)%3B%0A%09setX(123)%3B%0A%09alert(thing.x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Option%202%3A%20Use%20wrapping%20arrow%20function%0A%7B%0A%09let%20setX%20%3D%20(x%3Anumber)%3Avoid%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20thing.x%20%3D%20x%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20function%20type%20is%20inferred%0A%09setX(456)%3B%0A%09alert(thing.x)%3B%0A%7D).